# How do I find the sum of integers stored in a string array along with a string in java? I need the 0 in the output to be the sum of the integers

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, parseint

Input:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

```
    File gameScores = new File("C:\\Users\\jaret\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\GameScores.csv"); 
    if (gameScores.exists()) 
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String csvSplitBy = ",";
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gameScores));
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Games Report");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Gamer   1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
        System.out.println("    8   9   10  Total");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String list[] = new String[10];
            list = line.split(csvSplitBy);
            int sum = 0;
            for(String element:list) {
                try {
                    Integer num = Integer.parseInt(element);
                    sum += num;
                    }
                catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println(list[0] + "\t" 
                            + list[1] + (list[1].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[2] + (list[2].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[3] + (list[3].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[4] + (list[4].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[5] + (list[5].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[6] + (list[6].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[7] + (list[7].length() > 10 ? "\n\t" : "\n\t") 
                            + list[8] + (list[8].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[9] + (list[9].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[10] + "\t" + sum);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        br.close();
    }
```

---

---

### Games Report

---

### Gamer   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  Total

---

### Bob 167 123 159 102 102 189 183
173 197 148 0
Sally   189 130 138 113 159 116 134
196 150 144 0
Mario   104 106 120 188 143 189 149
174 163 100 0
Lev 152 159 195 140 154 176 107
128 166 181 0
Carden  158 200 175 114 117 150 176
181 131 132 0
Adelie  175 199 122 104 198 182 175
153 120 165 0
Lada    161 108 102 193 151 197 115
137 126 186 0
Xavier  178 171 147 113 107 129 128
189 165 195 0
Raffi   176 144 151 124 149 112 158
159 119 177 0
Chang   135 144 177 153 143 125 145
140 117 158 0
Mich    156 105 178 137 165 180 128
115 139 157 0
Mason   162 185 108 106 113 135 139
135 197 160 0
Cora    186 115 106 126 135 108 157
156 187 120 0
Sergio  117 105 115 116 193 200 176
134 122 153 0
Jonas   132 163 196 101 134 159 131
104 135 168 0

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If java 8 is fine, then you could use a more up-to-date approach:

```
        final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/your/file");
        final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

        int sum = 0;

        try {
            sum = lines.stream()
                    .map(line -> line.split(","))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .sum();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // do something with exception
        }

        lines.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(sum);
```

If the file is large, then play with `Files.lines(path)` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the first `element` in `list` is the name, which is not a number and you are getting NumberFormatException for that. And at that instance sum is 0 and catch is printing 0 for you as the sum.

If you want to print right sum, you should remove printing sum in catch and place it outside the for loop. As below:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String list[] = new String[10];
            list = line.split(csvSplitBy);
            int sum = 0;
            for(String element:list) {
                try {
                    Integer num = Integer.parseInt(element);
                    sum += num;
                    }
                catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println(list[0] + "\t" 
                            + list[1] + (list[1].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[2] + (list[2].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[3] + (list[3].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[4] + (list[4].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[5] + (list[5].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[6] + (list[6].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[7] + (list[7].length() > 10 ? "\n\t" : "\n\t") 
                            + list[8] + (list[8].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t")
                            + list[9] + (list[9].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") 
                            + list[10] + "\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum)
        }
```

Although I don't think it's a good Idea to handle it this way to print values in catch exception block.

Better solution could be something like below, where you iterate over list from index 1 to the end. As first index element is name. This way you will avoid unwanted Exception handling. And print outside the for loop.

Also removed that unwanted turnery operator.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String list[] = new String[10];
                list = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                int sum = 0;
                for(int i =1; i< list.length; i++) {
                    Integer num = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
                    sum += num;
                }

                 System.out.println(list[0] + "\t" 
                                + list[1] + "\t"
                                + list[2] + "\t" 
                                + list[3] + "\t"
                                + list[4] + "\t"
                                + list[5] + "\t"
                                + list[6] + "\t"
                                + list[7] + "\t"
                                + list[8] + "\t"
                                + list[9] + "\t"
                                + list[10] + "\t" + sum);
            }
```

Comment: When I try to use the second method of getting rid of the turnery operator it says that 'element' cannot be resolved to a variable. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Also, how would I go about printing the name of the gamer with the highest total score?

Comment: There was a build issue. I have updated answer to resolve that element can not be resolved issues. Please check now.

Comment: To print the gamer with highest total score create two variable highestScoreName and highestScore. Then keep on updating these variables after every iteration. I can not add that to answer as this was not in question.